# Expected class found object

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
ArrayList transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

public void printTransactions() {
    for(Transaction t: transactions)
        System.out.println("Transaction Type: " + t.getType() +
                           "\nDescription: " + t.getDescription() +
                           "\nAmount: " + t.getAmount() +
                           "\nNew Balance: " + t.getBalance() + 
                           "\nDate: " + t.getDate());
}
```

I'm new to Java and I have spent quite some time trying to figure out this error. In my `printTransactions()` method, it says starting with the for loop line "Error: Incompatible types required Transaction found Object"

What I have tried is cast `t` to a transaction class `Transaction(t).getType()` but that has not helped either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the generic type in `transactions` declaration. Try this

```
ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
```

Comment: Or `List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();` for Java 7+

Comment: @Reimeus Yes, absolutely.